# Getting "filter" to filter an entire array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying to write a function which filters an array of numbers from another array, but I can't seem to get it to work. For example, I have 2 arrays -

- `a`: `[1,2,3]`
- `b`: `[2,3]`

And I want my filter function to filter all the numbers in b from a, leaving me with an array only containing [1]. My code is as follows:

```
var args = [2,3];
var resulting = [1,2,3];

function destroy(val){
    return val !== args[];
}

resulting = resulting.filter(destroy);

return resulting;
```

Comment: are both arrays sorted?

Answer (score 0):

You're currently comparing a value to an array, which will always return false.

Here is a callback that should work :

```
function destroy(val){
    return args.indexOf(val) == -1;  // returns true if val isn't found in args
}
```

Or a lambda if you're ok with using ES6 :

```
val => !args.contains(val);  // returns true if val isn't found in args
```

Answer (score -2):

Filter out the items in args:

```
resulting.filter(function(item) {
    return item in args;
});
```

Comment: That won't work : the `in` operator when applied to arrays just check for a value at the provided index. `in` is better used with objects. [More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)